# Failed to resolve 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parcel

During Parcel compilation, this error occurs:

`@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'`

My `app.css` file:

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import './styles/style.scss';
@import './styles/plugins/plugins.scss';
@import './styles/plugins/plugins.css';
@import './styles/loader.scss';
@import './styles/custom.css';
```

Why is Parcel not recognizing the correct bootstrap SCSS?

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why this works, but creating a separate file fixes the problem:

```
@import './styles/bootstrap.scss';
```

Then in `bootstrap.scss`:

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to you use scss, you need to have sass installed and your css file must have scss extension. So try this:

1. Install sass from you project directory:`npm install -g sass`
2. Rename app.css file to app.scss and refactor  the project in order to avoid errors.